# can't unsubscribe on my ngrx selector call

Tags: ngrx

I have the following code

```
selectProduct(id){
    const sub = this.store$.select(ProductStoreSelector.selectProductByID(id)).subscribe((product) => {
      this.store$.dispatch(new ProductStoreAction.SetSelectedProduct({productID: product.id}));
      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
}
```

Basically, I would like to get my list of product, and get one by ID, then change my store state so that the selectedProduct become the one I just selected

```
export const featureAdapter: EntityAdapter<IProduct> = createEntityAdapter<IProduct>({
  selectId: model => model.id,
});
export const selectAllProducts: (state: object) => Array<IProduct> = featureAdapter.getSelectors(selectProductsState).selectAll;
export const selectProductByID = (id: string) => createSelector(
  selectAllProducts,
  (products) => products.find((product) => product.id === id)
);
```

and my store is an entityState of products with one selected

```
export interface State extends EntityState<IProduct> {
  selectedProduct: IProduct;
}
```

but the problem is,

althougt I do get my productId back, I can't unsubscribe to `sub.unsubscribe()` because it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either take(1) to listen for values only one time. Otherwise try to unsubscribe like below:

```
selectProduct(id){
   this.store$.select(ProductStoreSelector.selectProductByID(id)).subscribe((product) => {
      this.store$.dispatch(new ProductStoreAction.SetSelectedProduct({productID: product.id}));
    }).unsubscribe();
}
```

using take(1):

```
    selectProduct(id){
           this.store$.select(ProductStoreSelector.selectProductByID(id))
                .take(1)
                .subscribe((product) => {
                   this.store$.dispatch(new ProductStoreAction.SetSelectedProduct({productID: product.id}));
            });
        }
```

Comment: Try using .pipe(take(1)) in place of .take(1)